# Disabling "View" mentions from backend?

Tags: admin, front-end, editor, previews

I'm using wordpress as a content manager or something, so i'm using backend only (and i've disabled the frontend with a ghost theme which redirect to the admin panel).

The question is: how could i disable the "view" post button and generally every mention to "preview" posts, view categoryes, pages etc?

[image]

**Solved!**

Thank you cristian.raiber! It worked perfectly.
I've also put this lines to hide the previews in single posts:

```
function posttype_admin_css() {
global $post_type;
$post_types = array(
                        /* set post types */ 
                        'progetti',
                        'post',
                        'page',
                  );
    if(in_array($post_type, $post_types))
    echo '#post-preview, #view-post-btn{display: none;}';
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'posttype_admin_css' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'posttype_admin_css' );
```

add_action('admin_head', 'hide_quick_view');

function hide_quick_view() {
  echo '
    span.view {display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important;}
  ';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of disabling it, you'd be better off by hiding it using a bit of CSS trickery.

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
    add_action('admin_head', 'hide_quick_view');

function hide_quick_view() {
  echo '<style>
    span.view {display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important;}
  </style>';
}
```

This should be placed in your functions.php file.